# How to boost PDO SQLite inserts without transactions?

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

**Have following analog `INSERT` query which appears to be very slow!**

```
$sqlite = new \PDO();
for($i=0;$i<100;$i++) {
  $sqlite->prepare('INSERT INTO test (`id`, `data1`, `data2`) VALUES (:id, :data1, :data2);');
  $sqlite->execute(array(
    ':id' => NULL,
    ':data1' => 'some string',
    ':data2' = 'some string'
    // And more
  ));
}
```

**Executed 100 inserts** in 23.261 secs (4.3 q/s)

After setting `pragma synchronous = off;`

```
$sqlite->exec("pragma synchronous = off;");
```

**Executed 100 inserts** in 0.037 secs (2704.7 q/s)

- What side effects `pragma synchronous = off` may have?
- As far as I understand then bottleneck is fsync, right?
- Is there other way to speed SQLite up without using transactions to que queries?

Comment: Have you tried to first assemble a multi-row sql statement and execute it once at the end?

Comment: @Rasclatt That is basically same as using transaction `$sqlite->beginTransaction();` and `$sqlite->commit();`. I have here simplified example, but not all 100 queries are executed after each other so cant que these!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_synchronous) documents the side effects:

> With synchronous OFF (0), SQLite continues without syncing as soon as it has handed data off to the operating system. If the application running SQLite crashes, the data will be safe, but the database might become corrupted if the operating system crashes or the computer loses power before that data has been written to the disk surface. On the other hand, commits can be orders of magnitude faster with synchronous OFF.

Using a single transaction is the only safe way to insert many rows quickly. Just do it.

Comment: I guess that says it all.